# Point fixed to view (eg. cross of center view)

Tags: openlayers-3

What is the optimal way to position the **fixed point of view** (not to the point on the map). Using for showing middle of the view, while watching GPS positioning and moving center of the map according to current coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with pure html and css. Inside your map div, place another div:

```
<div id="map" class="map">
  <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

Then add some css to position it in the center of the map viewport:

```
#center {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    z-index: 10000;
    position: relative;
}
```

I created a JSFiddle so you can play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/wce6zqor/.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.
This method I tried too, but is there a problem if I want to move the map and drag-and-drop, start on this mark (overlay). Map will not move (logically: drag-and-drop does not begin on the object map, but on this overlap)

Answer (score 0):

Use an overlay with positioning center-center

```
var pos = map.getView().getCenter();  
pin = new ol.Overlay({
    position: pos,
    element: 'test',
    positioning: 'center-center'
});
map.addOverlay(pin);
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I ask wrong. I did not point in the center od actual view, but I thought the **point is still in the center of the view**. Just like the "+" and "-" zoom controls are displayed in the same location in the upper left corner.